# Addthis dynamically loading with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, addthis

I can't get this to work. I want to reload the **addthis** plugin everytime my ajax call fires. I am setting a new url with 'history.pushState' in javascript and want the plugin to get the new url to share it correctly.. Is this even possible?

(**addthis** is an social plugin) Example for the asynchronous loading can be found [here](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1293805-using-addthis-asynchronously#.UvfG2LQdTtk)

This is my html code:

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

This is my js code:

```
// initialize Addthis plugin when document is ready
$( document ).ready(function() {
 addthis.init()
});


function loadDynamicContent() {
// Code that will load the dynamic content

// Once that's all done, call addthis.toolbox()
addthis.toolbox('.addthis_toolbox')
}

// This ajax call fires when a button is clicked
function myCall() {
$.ajax({

type:"POST",
url:"ajax.php",
dataType:"json",
success:function(response){

loadDynamicContent();

},
error:function(response){

alert("error occurred");
}

});
            }
```

I am sure something is wrong in my logic to implement this.. I am kind of a beginner.
What is wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: Dou have any error in console?

Comment: No nothing. Everything seems ok (from js side)

Comment: check the response in networks...whether it is loaded or not

Comment: hm seems to work right. Is it even possible that the plugin grabs my new url if it was set by history.pushState before without a page reload? This is what i actually want to do

Comment: Do you have a page where we can see what is happening?  It looks like it should work.